# Run code by clicking an item in a ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm reconciling a database with pay period reports with three departments on three sheets.

I autofilter the pay period reports so I can compare the pay details with the database information on one sheet. The 3 departments are 2593, 2591, and 2590.

My macros autofilter the employees pay cheque details when I click the "Next" and "Previous" Button on Sheet1. It all works.

I also have a UserForm with a ListBox, so that I can manually select a particular employee rather than clicking "Next" through the list. The macros won't work and nothing is autofiltered.

I get

> Error Message 1004 Unable to get the CurrentRegion property of the Range Class.

I tried qualifying the workbooks/worksheets.

```vb
Sub ClearForNextRecord()
Dim rng As Range
'set the range on the REVIEW sheet to display the employee records and clean up range before the next record
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A15")
rng.CurrentRegion.Clear  '--ERROR APPEARS AT THIS LINE
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Start the extraction of records from the dept sheet onto the REVIEW sheet
Call Copy_AutoFiltered_VisibleRows_NewSheet 
   
End Sub
```

Comment: try activating that sheet and range currentRegion before clearing it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Abdullah!

Comment: I added this line :   Range(rng).Activate but I still got a run-time error: Method ‘Range’ of object ‘_Global’ failed

Comment: you have to activate that worksheet first. Also Can you check in Watch window if rng is initialized or not

Comment: Is this correct?      Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A15")
   Range(rng).Activate    I'm not very good with the Watch Window...but it says Value: Can't Compile Module    Type: Empty